# Is it possible to describe the places of $K$ purely in terms of the algebra of $\mathcal{O}_K$?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

By "purely in terms of the algebra" of $\mathcal{O}_K$, I mean without any reference to the real numbers, topological fields, etc.

Of course we can get the finite places by considering $\operatorname{Spec} \mathcal{O}_K$.  Can we get the others in some way, though, or are they inextricably linked to the idea of fields with metrics on them?

Comment: Perhaps there's an effective version of Dirichlet's unit theorem that gives the infinite places?